# How to receive specific data from URL to java

Tags: java, url

I need to get specific data from URL to java script and make it into a array.
The output should look like:
STATION:
MONTH:
YEAR:

Day    Min <----this means minimum temperature

1      59

2      51

3      34

4      26
etc.

Please help cut out the data that I don't need from the URL.
The code is:

//Create test class to output location, month and year, and temperature of each day (in an Array list).
      import java.net.*;
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class MinTemperatureTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Receive and create objects
    MinTemperature monthDay = new MinTemperature();
    MinTemperature monthTemperature = new MinTemperature();
    System.out.println("Weather Forecast");

    try {   
        //Create a URL object
        URL weatherURL = new URL("http://www.erh.noaa.gov/box/displayF6.php?Month=05&Year=13&Location=ORE");
        //Create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner (weatherURL.openStream());
        while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] result = line.split("\\s");
        for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
            System.out.println(result[x]);
    }

    //Create ArrayList
    ArrayList<MinTemperature> temperatures = new ArrayList<MinTemperature>();
    /*temperatures.add();

    for (MinTemperature t : temperatures) {
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }*/

    //Calculate minimum temperature value
    //int minimum = monthTemperature / monthDay;
    } //end try

    catch(java.net.MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid URL");
    }
    catch(java.io.IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("I/O Errors: no such file");
}

    } //end main method

} //end class
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's a Java HTML parser library which enables you to get the source of a webpage in a simple way. You should retrieve the source, extract the required elements and then create the array that you want.

Using JSoup: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

Parsing an exact element: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

For example:

```
//getting the web page source
Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yourpage.com").get();
//get all links in a page
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
//do something with them
for(Element link : links){
    //...
}
```